# Exclude Test files from precommit hook

Tags: python, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

Use case- Exclude all test files from flake8. In my project I have test files in different folders.

Current implementation:

```
  - repo: https://gitlab.com/PyCQA/flake8
    rev: 4.0.1
    hooks:
      - id: flake8
        exclude: ^tests
```

Current Output:

> integration-tests/test_1.py:21:1: F401 'pytest' imported but unused

Expected output: it should pass. It should not check tests.

Answer (score 4):

you've excluded things which match the pattern `^tests` and you have an error in `integration-tests`

your pattern needs to match those to exclude it properly

for example:

```yaml
repos:
  - repo: https://gitlab.com/PyCQA/flake8
    rev: 4.0.1
    hooks:
      - id: flake8
        exclude ^integration-tests/
```

or if you have both test paths, perhaps:

```yaml
        exclude: ^(tests|integration-tests)/
```

more on this in [the documentation](https://pre-commit.com/#regular-expressions)

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit